# JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken throws StackoverflowException

Tags: jwt, bearer-token, .net-4.8

I have the following configuration for my .Net Framework API :

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ...
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidIssuer = domain,
                        RequireSignedTokens = true,
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid),
                        SignatureValidator = (token, param) =>
                        {
                            var claims = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token, param, out var securitytoken);
                            return securitytoken;
                        }
                    }
                });
           ...
        }
```

My original issue is that the signature of the token is not checked, so I can temper it or forge a token and it goes through the API without any issues.
I tried to add the above signature validator but it generates a stack overflow exception.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the name of the method your code is part of?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Thanks! Have you figured out which methods are being called when the app freaks out?

Comment: I think the ValidateToken method call the SignatureValidator again and it goes into a recursive chain of calls.

Comment: I think you need to experimentally find this out. You could have a counter (a numeric field) incremented each time when the method you suspect is being called and throw an exception when it reaches, say 30. If you get such an exception, then your theory is proven to be correct.

Comment: I managed to do what I want in another part of the code where the calls are intercepted but I'll looking for a "proper" way to do it.